# Selenium 2 Automation Framework deployed as WAR on tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created a selenium 2 automation framework, using maven have packaged it into a WAR file.

After deploying build, when i start am getting my landing jsp, its a simple one, with a button as StartRun, on click of that i have initiated creation of WebDriver instance (am using ChromeDriver) and navigation to a specific URL.

But when i click on the button nothing happens,i have enabled log4j to capture all actions, so from logs i could see ChromeDriver instance is created, but am not able to see Chrome window opening up.

Am using selenium-2.44.0 and language is Java

Here is the piece of code where ChromeDriver instance is created :

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
captureLogs.info("Opening browser");
try {
    objectForTest(driver);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, happy to share more details if required.

Comment: Please post your Selenium configuration, and the ChromeDriver/WebDriver code so we can help you out.

Comment: You should NOT deploy WebDriver (with the war) to the application server. You just use the WebDriver jars with your test, in a normal JUnit Test.

Comment: @Ralph Ok, are you suggesting usage of RemoteWebDriver, if yes plese suggest how to use that as well.

Comment: You wrote that you put, WebDriver as well as Your Application under Test into (the same) war and deployed it. -- I told you not to put WebDriver into a WAR, because it is needed in the JVM that execute the tests, but not in the WebApplication that is tested.